# Why we cant 'throws' an exception from actionPerformed()

Tags: java, exception, action, actionlistener

I have a following code snippet in my project which works all fine. I was trying to propagate the PropertyVetoException back to the caller. Removing try-catch block and writting `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)throws PropertyVetoException`  is giving compilation error. Why is it so.? How can I propagate the exception back to the caller. I know event generating method is not a 'caller', but I want to propagate the exception to this event generating method indicating that exception has occurred and take the corrective actions.

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if(CMD_CHILD.equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
          if(child.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
              try {
                 child.setSelected(true);
              } catch (PropertyVetoException e1) {
                 e1.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Because the contract of `ActionListener` doesn't allow for it.  In this scenario, the caller won't really care.  Its probably being generated by a button on the screen.  What you may need to do, is provide some means by which the controller can deal with the exception in this situation, such as display and error message to valid the state of the application

Comment: The ActionListener interface defines what methods can be called, what arguments those methods may have and what exceptions that they may throw. This is known as a contract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `actionPerformed` is specified by the `ActionListener` interface, and in that interface, there's no `throws` to indicate that the method might throw any checked exceptions.

When overriding a method from a superclass or implementing a method from an interface, the overriding or implementing method cannot throw any more exceptions than what was specified in the superclass or interface.

Besides that, why would you want to do that? `actionPerformed` is called by the Swing GUI framework, what would you expect Swing to do with the exception?

Answer (score 4):

The interface you are implementing (`ActionListener`) does not declare an exception to the method `actionPerformed`. You can't change the method signature in your implementation class of that interface.

If you want to throw the exception to the event producer, then you can convert it to a `RuntimeException` which needs not to be declared in the method signature.

```
} catch (PropertyVetoEception e1) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e1);
}
```

Of course, `RuntimeException` is a little bit generic, you might define your own, application specific exception, such as:

```
public class EventExecutionException extends RuntimeException {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What would happen if you would throw a `RuntimeException` from the `actionPerformed` method? You will probably not get a pretty error message.

Comment: That's a different story. Your answer is much better than mine, of course.

Comment: IMHO, the biggest problem with Java checked exceptions is the lack of any means by which a block of code can *declaratively* say "I'm not expecting any methods called within this block to throw checked exception XX; if it does, re-throw wrapped in YY".  Checked exceptions would be useful if it was easy to ensure that a checked exception which escapes method `Foo` actually represents the situation in `Foo`'s documentation, and isn't really an exception thrown by some method which was called by `Foo` under circumstances that `Foo` wasn't expecting.